# Is the HTC Vive suitable for text-based productivity?

Tags: desktop, text-editing, vive

Considering purchasing an HTC Vive - trying to justify the price tag.

I have seen there are a few virtual desktop applications out there that can simulate 'big-screen' desktop experiences.

Are any of these experiences suitable for a few hours of emailing, word processing and/or programming? Is the resolution of this device sufficient to provide a comfortable (eg. non-eye-straining) experience whilst carrying out this kind of work? 
Or would it only be suitable for gaming and watching movies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without any answer from this community, I'll share what I've found elsewhere.

I posted the same question to Amazon users and received the following answer:

[Can this be used for text-based productivity (emails, word processing, programming etc.)? Or is the resolution insufficient for this?](https://www.amazon.co.uk/forum/-/TxRLXHBVNCH1HY/ref=ask_ql_ql_al_hza?asin=B01705N84M)

> Personally I think the resolution is too limited. You need to be so close to read small text that you can't really see much at once.
> You can do it however using an application called Virtual Desktop. I'm a programmer myself and it wasn't really suitable for me; it's much easier to work with my monitors.
> By Liam Foot on 13 August 2016